# Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@angular/localize/init' in '/usr/src/app/src'

Tags: angular, npm

I've added the @angular/localize package during an update from Angular 8 to 9. My polyfill.ts has the following import:

`import '@angular/localize/init';`

My app is compiling and spinning up fine on a browser locally but when I run a production build I'm getting the following error:

[image]

Any idea what isn't being resolved here? I can see the module installed correctly in the node_modules/@angular/localize directory.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Run this command in terminal
if you are using **npm**

```
npm install @angular/localize --save
```

or if you are using **Yarn**

```
yarn add @angular/localize
```

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that npm has installed appropriate version of @angular/localize! By default it installs the most latest, although for Angular 9 you need @angular/localize of version 9. That was the root cause of the issue in my case. This helped:

```
npm install --save @angular/localize@9.0.4
```